# Select with Select vs CTE - Performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between select using inside select and avoid select inside select and using CTE?

When I see the execution plan, there is no difference in execution plan?

Is there any difference in that?
When I use CTE, will it executed once or whenever I call CTE inside select, it will be called multiple times?

```
SELECT ID,
(SELECT TOP 1 [TEXT] FROM TABLEB B 
WHERE B.NAME ='ABC' AND B.CUSTOMER='ABC'
AND B.SERVICE=A.SERVICE AND B.USERID=DBO.fnGetUser()
ORDER BY DESC) 
FROM TABLEA A
```

Updated to:

```
WITH cte(SERVICE)
      AS
      (
           SELECT SERVICE FROM TABLEB B 
    WHERE B.NAME ='ABC' AND B.CUSTOMER='ABC'
 AND B.USERID=DBO.fnGetUser() 
      )
 SELECT ID,
    (SELECT  TOP 1 [TEXT] FROM cte B 
    WHERE B.SERVICE=A.SERVICE) 
    FROM TABLEA A
```

Comment: Non-recursive CTEs are functionally equivalent to subqueries (i.e. textual expansion of the CTE), with no difference between the two save for readability. In particular, the optimizer will not take special care to materialize the CTE results just once (just as it does not do so for subqueries). It may, but it also may not -- the only way to ensure that sort of thing is to use an explicit intermediate temp table.

Comment: As an aside -- assuming `dbo.fnGetUser()` is a scalar-valued function, the #1 approach to optimizing this query would be to rewrite it to a table-valued function that you can `CROSS APPLY`. The performance deficiencies of scalar-valued functions are well documented. By contrast, the optimizer is actually quite good at rewriting subqueries into joins where possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: You should put those comments as an answer.